# flowlayout control keeps adding control in the wrong direction in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, dynamic-controls, flowlayoutpanel

I have a flowlayout control in winforms, i have set its flow direction to TopDown but it keeps adding controls from left to right, autoscroll is also set to true.

```
flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Clear();    
Label labelInput = new Label();
ListBox listBoxNewInput = new ListBox();

//Initialize label's property
labelInput.Text = " #" + Convert.ToInt32(sequence);
labelInput.AutoSize = true;

//Initialize textBoxes Property
listBoxNewInput.HorizontalScrollbar = false;

listBoxNewInput.Items.Add(efforts);
//Add the newly created text box to the list of input text boxes
inputTextBoxesList.Add(listBoxNewInput);

//Add the labels and text box to the form
flowLayoutPanel1.FlowDirection = FlowDirection.TopDown;
flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(labelInput);
flowLayoutPanel1.FlowDirection = FlowDirection.TopDown;
flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(listBoxNewInput);
```

Comment: what i want is that if they dont fit vertically it should make a scroll bar, but it puts them on the right

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Set the `WrapContents` property of the `flowLayoutPanel1` to `false`, it will not allow to move those controls on the right if they don't fit. In order to be able to scroll clipped content you can set `AutoScroll` property to `true`

Here is the code:

```
flowLayoutPanel1.FlowDirection = FlowDirection.TopDown;
flowLayoutPanel1.WrapContents = false;
flowLayoutPanel1.AutoScroll = true;
flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(labelInput);
flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(listBoxNewInput);
```

Comment: OMG it would take weeks for me to solve this without someone directly say. cheers